# PHP - open, read and delete data from a file

Tags: php, fopen

I have a file called functions.php.

It contains a lot of data in over 3000 lines.

Somewhere in the middle of this file there is code:

```
/*****************************************
        My Custom Code 
*****************************************/

if ( function_exists('my_code') )
    my_code(array(
          'name' => 'First instance',
          'description' => 'Hello, hello.',
          ));

if ( function_exists('my_code') )     
    my_code(array(
          'name' => 'Second instance',
          'description' => 'Haha :)', 
          ));
```

I'm listing all my_code arrays and I'm getting:

- First Instance
- Second Instance

Now, what I want to achieve, is, when user clicks X next to "First instance" PHP opens functions.php file in the background, finds the exact function and deletes it without touching anything else.

So after deleting "First Instance" functions.php file should look like this:

```
/*****************************************
        My Custom Code 
*****************************************/

if ( function_exists('my_code') )     
    my_code(array(
          'name' => 'Second instance',
          'description' => 'Haha :)', 
          ));
```

Any idea how to achieve this? I know how to open files, write, delete, but I'm not sure how to wipe out not only a single line but a few lines around? :)

Comment: For the love of sanity, don't ever write code that is used to modify code

Comment: Gaah... the goggles, they do nothing! Don't do this. just set a variable somewhere and base the function call on that. `if ($first_call) { first(); } else { second(); }`

Comment: @Mark Baker, @Nick Weaver, @Marc B  to add or delete sidebar in Wordpress I have to add or remove code in fuctions.php, I don't think there is any other way: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: I'm not a Wordpress expert - but I can't believe that it forces you to use self-modifying code, else it would have died in the womb.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is always in the format you described you could read each 5 lines from your file and if it's the instance you want to keep, output them to a string. Then write the string back to the original file.

But again yes, code modifying code IS PAIN. Storing your instances in a data structure such as databases or a formatted file is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to open the file and loop through the lines. You'll need to match each line of your function, or you would need match the first line and track the number of open and close brackets `{ }` to know when you've reached the end of it.

If a line doesn't match you write that out to a new file. If it does match you ignore it. Then finally you make an system call to do a syntax check on the new file (in case something went wrong with your line matching):

```
system( "php -l newfile.php", &$retval );
```

Then check the return value `$retval` to make sure it was ok (it will be exactly equal to 0). If it is okay then you overwrite functions.php with your new file.

```
if( $retval === 0 ) {
     // the syntax is good 
     rename( "newfile.php", "functions.php");
}
```

You would need to set the appropriate paths for this to work.

Now all of that said, this is not a very good idea and I would advise you not to implement it. A better method would be to break your functions out into separate files. Then use an INI config file or a database to keep track of what you should load. Either of those have the ability to be edited. Even a text data file would be better than mucking with the actual code.

Once you know what you're supposed to load then at the beginning require or include the appropriate file.

Here's a simple example of doing it with a database:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT file_name FROM load_functions");
if( mysql_error() ) {
     // do something because the query failed
}
else {
     while( list($file_name) = mysql_fetch_row($res) ) {
          if( file_exists($file_name) ) {
               require_once( $file_name );
          }
          else {
               // warn because a file requested didn't exist
          }
     }
}
```

Hope that helps